# Multiple views side-by-side windows-like AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to do something similar to Azure portal with ui-router/angularjs.

[image]

When a user clicks on a link, I want to open a new window and load the template related to the link. It's possible to "drag" all windows from left to right or right to left when many are open. I thought it would be possible to manage it by using a ui-view for each new window opened, but it seems that we can't setup dynamic view name for a state. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you!